# Jquery tabs enable tab?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I am trying to enable a disabled tab in Jquery but it doesn't work. I have my tabs:

```
<!--Jquery AJAX Tabs Start-->
<div id="signuptabs">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="type.php"><span>type</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ber.php"><span>mber</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ces.php"><span>ces</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ups.php"><span>ups</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="t.php"><span>ext</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="nu.php"><span>u</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="nfo.php"><span>ion</span></a></li>
     </ul>

</div>
<!--Jquery AJAX Tabs End-->
```

Then I have my Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signuptabs").tabs({ disabled: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] });

//number type button
$('#target').click(function() {
$('#signuptabs').enableTab(2); // enables third tab
 });

 });
```

I have a button with an ID 'target' that when clicked is supposed to enable the (2) tab. The tabs show as disabled but will not enable. What is wrong??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The call to the [`enable` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-enable) is a alightly different syntax than you currently have, like this:

```
$('#signuptabs').tabs('enable', 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

this also works to enable a tab 2 and disable tab 1 and 3

```
$("#signuptabs").tabs('select',1);
    $("#signuptabs").tabs({disabled: [0,2]});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is way works for me:

```
$('#signuptabs').tabs("option", "disabled", false, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

Each tab index is zero-based, so you should start you first tab with "0" index.